# Is $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t \to 0$ correct with limit? What does this expression mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

In one source I saw the expression $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t \to 0$.

For this expression it was limit: $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{x(t)-y(t)}{t}=0$

Is $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t \to 0$ correct with this limit? What does $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t$ \to $0$ mean? What does $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{x(t)-y(t)}{t}=0$ mean?

Thanks.

Comment: $x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$ for $t\to0$ means exactly that $\lim_{t\to0}(x(t)-y(t))/t=0$. The notation $o(h(t))$ means a function $r(t)$ (maybe assumed continuous or whatever) such that $\lim_{t\to0}r(t)/h(t)=0$

Comment: @FShrike How to prove it? Does $x(0)$ equal to $y(0)$?

Comment: You don't prove it. How could we (without further context)? You haven't told us what $x$ and $y$ are, at the moment they could be essentially any function. I'm just explaining what the $o$ notation means. It just means what you already said it means, that $\lim_{t\to0}(x(t)-y(t))/t=0$. This is by definition of "$x(t)=y(t)+o(t)$" or of $x(t)-y(t)\in o(t)$

Comment: @FShrike $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are continuous functions.

Comment: That doesn't tell us enough. Of course $x(0)=y(0)$ is forced but it is **not** sufficient or equivalent to the statement $x(t)-y(t)\in o(t)$. I think this is a case of: seeing a definition and thinking this is something you have to prove rather than just accept and understand. Or maybe what you're really asking is: why is it true that $x(t)-y(t)\in o(t)$? But to answer that we need to see the original source, there is just not enough context; you need to put the work into writing a more detailed question.

Comment: @FShrike [source, pdf , page 6](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870810001465)

Comment: You're not putting in the effort of writing a question that asks what you actually want to know. Please, edit the question with more focus. What the question itself has asked, I have already "answered".

Comment: @FShrike You wrote in comment #1 that "The notation o(h(t)) means ...". But how does this relate to $x(t) = y(t) + o(t)$ and to $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{x(t)-y(t)}{t}=0$? I can't understand. It's my question.

Comment: Take $h(t)=t$ for all $t$. I was just remarking that $o$ notation is very general. Look, $x(t)-y(t)=o(t)$ is the statement. **By definition**, this means: $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{x(t)-y(t)}{t}=0$$There is no difference in meaning; the little-$o$ notation is just a succinct notation to say that limit is zero.

Comment: @FShrike big thanks!